# Brezis' hint for exercise 8.21.1: how to obtain $1 \leq \|v_0' \|_1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I'm trying to solve a problem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 8.21** Assume that $p \in C^1([0,1])$ with $p(x) \geq \alpha>0 \quad \forall x \in[0,1]$ and $q \in$ $C([0,1])$ with $q(x) \geq 0 \quad \forall x \in[0,1]$. Let $v_0 \in C^2([0,1])$ be the unique solution of
> $$
> (1) \quad 
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> -\left(p v_0^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}+q v_0=0 \quad \text { on }[0,1],\\
> v_0(0)=1, v_0(1)=0
> \end{array} \right.
> $$
>
> Set $k_0=v_0^{\prime}(0)$.
>
> 1. Check that $k_0 \leq-\alpha / p(0)$.
>    [**Hint:** Multiply equation $(1)$ by $v_0$ and integrate by parts. Use the fact that $1 \leq \|v_0' \|_1 \le \|v_0' \|_2$.]

I could not see how the solution of $(1)$ satisfies $1 \leq \|v_0' \|_1$. Could you please elaborate on this hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $1 = v_0(0) - v_0(1) = - \int_0^1 v_0'$, so $1 = |\int_0^1 v_0'| \le \int_0^1 |v_0'|=\|v_0' \|_1$.